# GAUT HLS tool error : "No alternatives to process, unable to select best one"

Tags: c, vhdl

I am trying to synthetise the following C code by using GAUT tool:

```
#define N 16


int main (const int tab[N], int* out)
{

//  static const int tab[N] =        {98,-39,-327,439,950,-2097,-1674,9883,9883,-1674,-2097,950,439,-327,-39,98};


  int k = 0, i=1;

  for( i = 1; i < N; i++)
{   

      // invariant : k est l'indice du plus petit
      // élément de x[0..i-1]
      if(tab[i] < tab[k])
          k = i;
}

  *out = tab[k];
  return 0;     
 }
```

Simple program to find the minimum in an array.
It successfully compiles, generates a DFG that seems to be honest.
However when I try to synthetise, I get this error:
"No alternatives to process, unable to select best one"
And thus can't go on with the implementation flow.

Does anyone know what is the problem? I am facing it with other such small test programs as well. I hope some specialist will be able to answer.

Thank you.

Comment: GAUT is NOT a widely used or well-known tool. You'd better give a few references if you want any chance to have an answer.

Comment: Yeah I already noticed... What kind of references however?

Answer (score 2):

Since this is tagged VHDL, perhaps it's worth looking at a straight VHDL port, bypassing the tool completely. This only took a few minutes, and it's in three parts:

1) VHDL has a quirk in that to use an array as a port parameter, it must be a named type (int_array). (C has a different quirk passing arrays around : it doesn't, it passes a pointer instead)

```
package Types is
type int_array is array (natural range <>) of integer;
end Types;

package body Types is
end Types;
```

2) The bit that does the work: I left the C code in as a comment to illustrate how closely they correspond:

```
use Work.Types.all;

-- int main (const int tab[N], int* out)
entity MinArray is
   Generic ( N : Natural);
   Port ( Tab : in int_array;
           Output : out integer );
end MinArray;

architecture Behavioral of MinArray is
--  int k = 0, i=1;
-- for( i = 1; i < N; i++)
--   {   
--      if(tab[i] < tab[k])
--          k = i;
--   }
--  *out = tab[k];
--  return 0;     
--}
begin
   Process(Tab) is
    variable k : natural;
    begin
       k := 1;
       for i in tab'range loop
           if tab(i) < tab(k) then
               k := i;
          end if;
        end loop;
       Output <= tab(k);
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

3) A test harness:

```
  use Work.Types.all;

  ENTITY tester IS
     Port ( Minimum : out integer );
  END tester;

  ARCHITECTURE behavior OF tester IS 

--#define N 16
-- static const int tab[N] =        {98,-39,-327,439,950,-2097,-1674,9883,9883,-1674,-2097,950,439,-327,-39,98};

  constant N : natural := 16;
  constant tab : int_array (1 to N)  := (98,-39,-327,439,950,-2097,-1674,9883,9883,-1674,-2097,950,439,-327,-39,98 );

  BEGIN
          uut: entity work.MinArray 
                Generic Map (N => N)
                PORT MAP(
                Tab => Tab,
                 Output => Minimum );

  END;
```

Note that this is all synthesisable in Xilinx XST,

```
Advanced HDL Synthesis Report

Macro Statistics
# RAMs                                                 : 1
 32x32-bit single-port distributed Read Only RAM       : 1
# Comparators                                          : 15
 32-bit comparator greater                             : 15
# Multiplexers                                         : 32
 1-bit 2-to-1 multiplexer                              : 24
 2-bit 2-to-1 multiplexer                              : 1
 3-bit 2-to-1 multiplexer                              : 4
 4-bit 2-to-1 multiplexer                              : 3
```

but (because the input tables are a constant array) all the above hardware disappears in the optimisation stage.

Now one of the important things in high level synthesis is to explore different datatypes such as different word widths; such as the 15-bit word required to store the test data. To explore this, let's just modify the "Types" package as follows:

```
type small_int is range -16384 to 16383;
type int_array is array (natural range <>) of small_int;
```

I also changed the Output port type to small_int. And as we can see from the synthesis report, hardware usage has been reduced accordingly.

```
Macro Statistics
# RAMs                                                 : 1
 32x15-bit single-port distributed Read Only RAM       : 1
# Comparators                                          : 15
 15-bit comparator greater                             : 15
# Multiplexers                                         : 32
 1-bit 2-to-1 multiplexer                              : 24
 2-bit 2-to-1 multiplexer                              : 1
 3-bit 2-to-1 multiplexer                              : 4
 4-bit 2-to-1 multiplexer                              : 3
```

So perhaps a question is : how much easier do the C tools make exploring the design space like custom word widths?

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer, that I read thoroughly. However it is part of my project to study Gaut in fact. Anyway thank you again, I learnt a few things nonetheless :)